# Redux-form v6 isDirty (and isPristine) selector not triggering re-render on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form, immutable.js

I am trying to detect whether the form state is dirty from a parent component so I can only display a submit button if the form values have been changed..

The initial render shows false as expected but changing the values does not trigger a re-render with the new vlaue..

```
import React from 'react'
import { isDirty } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

<Parent>
  { props.isDirty ? <SubmitButton /> : null }
  <Form {...etc} />
</Parent>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...
  isDirty: isDirty('myForm')(state),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Parent)
```

Console logging `props.isDirty` shows that at the initial render of `<Parent/>` `isDirty` is false. However, changing the values does not trigger a re-render of `<Parent/>` with the new value.

**Update:**

After further investigation, I think this is a bug:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(isDirty('myForm')(state)
  return {
    ...
    isDirty: isDirty('myForm')(state),
  }
```

Here, changing form values triggers `mapStateToProps` as expected but `isDirty` is always false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doh! Not a bug. I was importing the wrong, mutable `isDirty` selector..

`import { isDirty } from 'redux-form/immutable'`

..solved the problem

Comment: You should select this as the accepted answer to your question.

Comment: I did as you said, and installed immutable from NPM. Now I am getting a PropType and CreateClass deprecation warning. Did you have that issue?

Comment: Did not solve it for me